# How to clean all input box, textarea data from table rows without removing rows?

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I am trying to clean all input box, textarea data from a table without removing rows.

I can remove rows using

```
$('#myTableRow').remove();
```

but I don't know how to clean data from rows without removing it.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
$("#table_name > tbody > tr").each(function(){
  $(this).find("input:text,textarea").each(function(){
    $(this).val('');
  });
});
```

Comment: Make it more easy   $("#table_name > tbody > tr input:text,textarea").val('');

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are talking about html/text and attributes of a row, so I guess you can do this:

Let's say #myTableRow has this code:

```
<th id="myTableRow" data-x="Lorem" data-z="Ipsum">
    <br>
    <div style="color: white">Chickens</div>
</th>
```

You can do `$('#myTableRow').html('')` as mentioned as the answer previously. Also, you can do `$('#myTableRow').data('x', '')` and `$('#myTableRow').data('y', '')` to clear those values.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
 $('#myTableRow td input[type=text]').val('');
 $('#myTableRow td textarea').val('');
```

See code snippet below...

```js
$(function(){
  $('a').click(function(){
      $('table td input[type=text]').val('');
      $('table td textarea').val('');
    });
  });
```

```css
table{
  border-collapse:collapse
  }
td{
  border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
  padding:5px;
  }
a{
  color:Maroon;
  font-weight:bold;
  cursor:pointer;
  font-family:Arial;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><td><input type=text value="Text box 1"/></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type=text value="Text box 2"/></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type=text value="Text box 3"/></td></tr>
  <tr><td><textarea>Veeeeery Long text</textarea></td></tr>
 </table>

<br/><br/>

<a>Clear All</a>
```